# Lium speaker diarization (recognition software) Null Pointer issue

Tags: java, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use the speaker diarization program called Lium with a command line or inside a java program with no luck.

On the command line version, i get a null pointer exception message :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at fr.lium.spkDiarization.lib.MainTools.readGMMContainer(MainTools.java:222)

at fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Diarization.speech(Diarization.java:193)

at fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Diarization.ester2Version(Diarization?java:318)

at fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Diarization.main(Diarization.java:530)
```

in the java program, the output file is created but the size is 0 bytes.

to try the program :

- download the jar from here http://lium3.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/download
- create a .bat file with that inside :

  java -Xmx1024m -jar ./LIUM_SpkDiarization-4.2.jar --fInputMask=./soundfile-16Khz-16Bits.wav --sOutputMask=./showName.seg --doCEClustering showName

the program should create a file named showName.seg containing the speaker segments.

but i have the error message. I tried every version of the software with the same result.

If you want to try the software inside a java program, use the code inside diarization.java in the source code

I appreciate a lot any help. thanks a bunch.

Jeff

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue, it is related to wrong file separator used in the program.
Java is expecting `/` as separator in resource locator while the code tries to use the local separator`\` in Windows.

If you can recompile the jar file (use ant) all that needs to be done is to replace `File.separator` with `/` in the `src\fr\lium\spkDiarization\system\Diarization.java` file; thas it worked for me.

Lines 192, 229, 245, 265 and 471 require this simple change, for example in line 245:

```
 URL genderURL = getClass().getResource(dir + File.separator + "gender.gmms");
```

Should be :

```
 URL genderURL = getClass().getResource(dir + "/" + "gender.gmms");
```

Answer (score 0):

With the jar provided on the website it works fine and produces results.

The error is that it tries to find a data file inside the jar and fails to do that (the file is ester2/gender.sms).

It might be that you recompiled the jar or built it from sources and the new updated jar didn't have that file

Another possibility is that you might use some other JVM (not Oracle) which is not that good in finding resources inside the jar.

As a last way to fix the problem you can extract the data files to a folder and fix the sources to read them from a folder, not from the jar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in loading gender.sms in windows system. I have the same issue. Under linux it runs successfully. And on my windows 7 it's crashing. According to the project site, they know about problem:

> Caution: there is a problem not yet solve under windows. The load of
>   resources (as gmm) don't works.